# Oracle streams replication error "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, stream

Oracle version the same in two hosts 11g
I want to create schema replication with my first database to second and it return error, ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-23616: Failure in executing block 6 for script
E367A59F534C71FAE050000AA11F7E9A with
ORA-06550: line 43, column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 43, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RECO_SCRIPT_INVOK", line 139
ORA-06512
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RECOVERABLE_SCRIPT", line 659
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RECOVERABLE_SCRIPT", line 682
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STREAMS_MT", line 7972
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STREAMS_ADM", line 2674
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STREAMS_ADM", line 2735
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

The block has errors its

```
-- 
-- Datapump SCHEMA MODE IMPORT
-- 
DECLARE
  h1                NUMBER := NULL; -- data pump job handle
  schema_expr_list  VARCHAR2(32767); -- for metadata_filter
  cnt               NUMBER; -- temp variable
  object_owner      dbms_utility.uncl_array; -- obj owners
  job_state         VARCHAR2(30); -- job state
  status            ku$_Status; -- data pump status
  job_not_exist     exception;
  pragma            exception_init(job_not_exist, -31626);
  local_compat            v$parameter.value%TYPE;
  remote_compat            v$parameter.value%TYPE;
  min_compat            v$parameter.value%TYPE;
  ind               NUMBER; 
  le                ku$_LogEntry;  -- For WIP and error messages
  js                ku$_JobStatus; -- The job status from get_status 
  jd                ku$_JobDesc; 
-- The job description from get_status
BEGIN

  object_owner(1) := 'MY_CHEMA';
  FOR idx IN 1..1 LOOP
    -- schema does not exist locally, need instantiation
    IF schema_expr_list IS NULL THEN
      schema_expr_list := '(';
    ELSE
      schema_expr_list := schema_expr_list ||',';
    END IF;
    schema_expr_list := schema_expr_list||''''||object_owner(idx)||'''';
  END LOOP;
  IF schema_expr_list IS NOT NULL THEN
    schema_expr_list := schema_expr_list || ')';
  ELSE
    COMMIT;
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  select value into local_compat from v$parameter
  where name = 'compatible';
  select value into remote_compat from v$parameter@SECOND_DB
  where name = 'compatible';
  IF TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(local_compat, '.', '0')) > TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(remote_compat, '.', '0')) THEN
    min_compat := remote_compat;
  ELSE
    min_compat := local_compat;
  END IF;
  h1 := dbms_datapump.open(operation=>'IMPORT',job_mode=>'SCHEMA',
    remote_link=>'',
    job_name=>NULL, version=> min_compat);



  dbms_datapump.add_file(
    handle=>h1,
    filename=>'expdat1.dmp',
    directory=>'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
    filetype=>dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
  dbms_datapump.add_file(
    handle=>h1,
    filename=>'expdat1.dlg',
    directory=>'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
    filetype=>dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);

  dbms_datapump.start_job(h1);

  job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
  BEGIN
    WHILE (job_state != 'COMPLETED') AND (job_state != 'STOPPED') LOOP
      status := dbms_datapump.get_status(
        handle => h1,
        mask => dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
                dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
                dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,
        timeout => -1);
      job_state := status.job_status.state;
      dbms_lock.sleep(10);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION WHEN job_not_exist THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('job finished');
  END;
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Exception, sql code = ' || SQLCODE || ', error message: ' || SQLERRM);
  dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
  dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);

  IF h1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
    BEGIN 
      dbms_datapump.get_status( 
        handle    => h1, 
        mask      => dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error + 
                     dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
                     dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip, 
        timeout   => -1, 
        job_state => job_state,
        status     => status );

      dbms_output.put_line('Data pump job status: ' || job_state);
      le := status.wip; 
      IF le IS NULL THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('WIP info is NULL'); 
      ELSE 
        dbms_output.put_line('WIP info:'); 
        ind := le.FIRST; 
        WHILE ind IS NOT NULL LOOP 
          dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText); 
          ind := le.NEXT(ind); 
        END LOOP; 
      END IF; 

      le := status.error; 
      IF le IS NULL THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('Error info is NULL'); 
      ELSE 
        dbms_output.put_line('Error info:'); 
        ind := le.FIRST; 
        WHILE ind IS NOT NULL LOOP 
          dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText); 
          ind := le.NEXT(ind); 
        END LOOP; 
      END IF; 
    EXCEPTION  
      WHEN job_not_exist THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('Data pump job finished');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE; 
    END; 
  END IF; 
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE;
END;
```

but I manually doing Import to second database, log file all is clean, no errors, and tables, views same as first schema, what is problem???

Comment: Based on your code, this is about Oracle Datapump, not Streams. They are not the same thing (Streams was deprecated and replaced by GoldenGate).

Comment: I don't know Golden Gate technologies and this code from Streams when the DB doing Impdp

Comment: Your error is from your stored procedure: `ORA-06550: line 43, column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. What Datapump options did you use when loading data from the command line?